# Can't login to a web site with python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import webbrowser
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests
import urllib
import re
import time
import math ## i know some of the imports are unnecessary, but i just copy paste them everywhere

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

j=0
proxies = {'http': "http://213.6.68.78:53281",
           'https': "https://213.6.68.78:53281"}

login_data = {
    'username': 'my_nickname420',
    'password': 'password1234',
    'phone': '' 
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    while(1):
        try:
            s.proxies = proxies
            break
        except:
            print('error in connecting to proxy... ')

    url = "https://www.TOPSECRETSITE.com/login"
    r = s.get(url)
    page_soup = soup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    login_data['_csrf'] = page_soup.find('input', attrs={'name': '_csrf'})    ['value']
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

---

When I run the code, it gives me an output but somehow I'm still not connected to site, it shows me as guest user.

Here is the things you see when you click inspect element after logging(normally from browser)

```
*Form Data 

username: my_nickname420

password: password1234

_csrf: m4beGyaG-CGYiSd2PHSjt3yFyHBsK1YP4GbI

phone:
```

There is also some "set cookie" things in above this, if that helps.

Comment: What is the point of putting `s.proxies = proxies` in a try/except?  How can it possibly fail?

Comment: Sometimes the proxy I'm using is just doesn't work. And after waiting like 5 secs it works normally. I didn't want to re-run the code manually every time, so thats why I put try-catch here. Trust me I see a lot of  "'error in connecting to proxy" warnings

Comment: But simply _assigning_ the proxies can't fail, right?  The failure would happen in the `s.get()` or `s.post()` call.

Comment: maybe you are right, I might be confused a little. But this is not my main problem right now

Comment: Does `r.content` contain any obvious error messages?

Comment: no it doesn'ttt

Comment: if without proxy it is work?

Comment: no because site is blocked in my country. only way is using proxy...